# Do WSUS Reports Included Updates Awaiting Approval?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, wsus, update

If I create a WSUS report as follows:

```
Type: Summary
Classifications: Critical, Security, Service Packs
Products: Any
Groups: Foo
Status: Needed
```

Will it include updates that have been synchronized but have not been approved or declined yet? Part of my confusion is that I am also not entirely clear on what needed means technically in the WSUS context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates that are "Not Approved" or even "Declined" will show up with the rest.